# Cauchy sequence and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

We know that every Cauchy sequence is bounded. and the converse may not be true.
but if we define a sequence $x_n=n$ with metric $d(m,n)$=$\lvert \dfrac{1}{m}-\dfrac{1}{n}\rvert$. then this  is a Cauchy sequence but our sequence was unbounded.

My question is that does 
necessary condition of boundedness gets affected if we change the metric condition on the space.

Comment: How is that sequence unbounded? $d(x_n,1)<2$ for all $n$

Comment: Every integer sequence is bounded with this metric.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence *is* bounded, since $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):d(x_n,1)\leqslant1$.

On the other hand, yes, a set being bounded depends upon the metric, as your example shows.